# How to input data to use GenomicRanges packages to analyze in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, genomicranges

I would like to make data like this one

```
library(Gviz)
library(GenomicRanges)
#Load data : class = GRanges
data(cpgIslands)
cpgIslands
## GRanges with 10 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
##        seqnames               ranges strand
##                         
##    [1]     chr7 [26549019, 26550183]      *
##    [2]     chr7 [26564119, 26564500]      *
##    [3]     chr7 [26585667, 26586158]      *
##    [4]     chr7 [26591772, 26593309]      *
##    [5]     chr7 [26594192, 26594570]      *
##    [6]     chr7 [26623835, 26624150]      *
##    [7]     chr7 [26659284, 26660352]      *
##    [8]     chr7 [26721294, 26721717]      *
##    [9]     chr7 [26821518, 26823297]      *
##   [10]     chr7 [26991322, 26991841]      *
##   ---
##   seqlengths:
##    chr7
##      NA
#Annotation track, title ="CpG"
atrack <- AnnotationTrack(cpgIslands, name = "CpG")
plotTracks(atrack)
```

and this is my data

```
id  chr start   end
wnt4    1A  14938532    14938648
wnt5    1A  14940394    14940633
wnt6    1A  14943914    14944217
wnt7    1A  14945438    14945867
wnt1    1A  14946238    14946546
```

My question is how to make my data look like data above?

anyone can help me? I am not really familiar to input data.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can import the data in R as a dataframe than apply the function makeGRangesFromDataFrame as explained here [https://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/GenomicRanges/html/makeGRangesFromDataFrame.html](https://web.mit.edu/%7Er/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/GenomicRanges/html/makeGRangesFromDataFrame.html)